# I am not able to access private variables of class, I have used friend class

Tags: class, c++17, friend

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    class Movie
    {
    private:
        std::string name{};
        std::string rating{};
        int watched{};
        friend class movies;
    public:
        Movie(std::string name_val, std::string rating_val, int watched_val = 0);
     // copy constructor
        Movie(const Movie &source);  //// this constructor
    };
    
    Movie::Movie(std::string name_val, std::string rating_val, int watched_val)
        :name{name_val}, rating{rating_val}, watched{watched_val}{}

    Movie::Movie(const Movie &source){
        name = source.name;
        rating = source.rating;
        watched = source.watched;
    }
    class Movies
    {
    private:
        std::vector<Movie> movie_obj;

    public:
        void get_movie_byname(Movie &abc) { std::cout << abc.name; }; // here is error abc.name
    };
```

```
here is the error message
 main.cpp:53:53: error: 'std::string Movie::name' is private within this context
53 |     void get_movie_byname(Movie &abc) { std::cout << abc.name; };
   |                                                     ^~~~
main.cpp:11:21: note: declared private here
  11 |         std::string name {};
     |                     ^~~~
```

cant understand whats wrong...
i think friend of a class is friend of for given obj ( this--> ), and not for all obj,
if i removed copy constructor of Movie, error resolved!
cant understand relation between copy constructor and friend.

// issue solved turns out its just typo in Movies, declaration in friend declaration.

Comment: typo? `movies` or `Movies`

Comment: @Nimrod yeah it's a typo in the friend declaration, thanks